# Centos 5.6 NetInstaller network issues

Tags: centos, centos5

I burnt into a CD the netinstaller provided by Centos 5.6.
At boot time the installer comes up and after I choose the HTTP option for installation I choose the "Dynamic IP configuration (DHCP)" option. Now, a popup saying:

```
Sending request for IP information for eth0...
```

is stuck and nothing happens. I have connected a cable from the computer to the router..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the router works and you were able to use the same PC (or another PC) to obtain an IP address, I suspect that the installer is looking for an IPv6 address. I recall that in a number of cases, the installer will hang if it is unable to obtain an IPv6 address (not sure if it is because the router does not support ipv6 or something else entirely).

I would suggest that during the installation to disable ipv6 before obtaining an network address via DHCP. If that doesn't work, I would suggest that you do either a [control+alt+F3 or control+alt-ctl4](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/ch-guimode-x86.html) to see if you are actually getting a DHCP response.

Comment: Rilindo: I can see that DHCP cpmfiguration failed (timed out). What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Let me ask to make sure: are you sure that you able to to use the same router with another computer with no issues? Is it failing at obtaining an IPv4 address? 

Can we get the router address as well as netmask and gateway?

Comment: For that matter, also the model name and number of the router.

Comment: Rilindo: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I was able to connect with other computers to that router ..I disabled IPv6 so it fails on IPv4 ... the router address: 10.0.0.138, Subnetmask : 255.0.0.0. The router is Siemens ADSL-SL2-141. Thanks!

Comment: I might suggest you configure with a static IP during the installation. if you router address is 10.0.0.138, use that as the gateway and select a free address within the 10.0.0.0/8 network.